# Django: write SQL code from Model.save() in text file

Tags: python, django, postgresql

How can I overwrite a `model.save()` method to write every SQL code it generates on a text file?

I am working with PostgreSQL, and it would also work if I did this on a database level (write every SQL code that changes a table on a text file).

Comment: you could use PostgreSQL logs http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-logging.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the raw queries with `django.db.connection.queries`. [More info here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running).

So examine that object in your save method and write the newest query to a file.